# My python code works in one VM and not in the other ... complaining about quotes

Tags: python, double-quotes, single-quotes

I have 2 VM sessions.

In the VM session A, the script won't run right if I type python

[if I don't put python3 the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BvXu.png)

but if I type python3  it's fine.

When I move this script to my other VM session B, and I try to run it, it is spitting out (what I think) are issues with quotes. (VM B is a virtualized environment and I don't usually have to type python3  .. but I did it both ways here and it still fails.

[the error I get in VMWare B no matter what I do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2vmF.png)

VM A is running python Python 2.7.15rc1 -- at least if I type python on the terminal it says that ... which confuses me why I type python3 to get it to run. I see code that is using some of the new formatting in python strings.

VM B is running Python 3.5.2.

Can someone help, I am a rookie here big time ... so appreciate it!

Comment: Your errors are not images, they are text. Please copy them as such in your question.

Comment: On your VM A `python` is running Python 2.7 and `python3` is running some version of Python 3.x.  The two are not comparable.

Comment: f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6 but you're running Python 3.5 on VMWare B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script uses f-strings (the `f"\t- {house_1[0]} sq feet"` thing), which were only added to Python in version 3.6.  You need to either upgrade the Python 3 version on VM B or else rewrite your code to no longer use f-strings.

Comment: re: rewriting, just use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) instead.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that one ... grrrrr ... thanks!